# How to use the value of text field to dynamically create upload URL?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm creating a web client to upload multiple files to Pinterest, purely for personal purposes. The front end is an AngularJS, has a text box and an file upload element from [kendo-ui](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload). I've not done front end development for years, and never seriously, and for one single page, I don't want to start now. So I put together a page mostly by copy-pasting from multiple places.

That said, the problem I'm running into is that the Kendo upload element has a `saveUrl` that, as the name suggests, posts the selected files to the given URL. For my purposes, and to remain true to REST, I'd like to form the `saveUrl` by appending the value of the text box in the end. I've no clue how to achieve this, so here we are.

Following is what I've done so far; what I'm looking for is to append the value of `board` to `saveUrl`, so if user types 'whatever' in the text box `board`, the `saveUrl` should become `save/whatever`.

```
<div id="main" ng-app="Pinterest">
    <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="PinterestController">
        <div>
            <h4>Board Name</h4>
            <input type="text" id="board" name="board" class="k-textbox" required style="width: 400px;"/>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 2em;">
            <h4>Upload files</h4>
            <input name="files"
                   type="file"
                   kendo-upload
                   k-async="{ saveUrl: 'save', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: false }"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    angular.module("Pinterest", ["kendo.directives"])
        .controller("PinterestController", function($scope){
        })


    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself, no thanks to anyone here.

```
<body>
<div id="main" ng-app="pinterest">
    <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="PinterestController">
        <div>
            <h4>Board Name</h4>
            <input type="text" id="board" name="board" class="k-textbox" required style="width: 400px;"
                   ng-model="modelObj.board"/>
            <p class="demo-hint">Will be created if doesn't exist</p>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 2em;">
            <h4>Upload files</h4>
            <input name="files"
                   type="file"
                   kendo-upload
                   k-async="{ saveUrl: 'pinterest/{board}', autoUpload: false }"
                   k-upload="onUpload"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("pinterest", ["kendo.directives"]);
  app.controller("PinterestController", function($scope) {
    $scope.modelObj = {
      board: $scope.board
    };
    $scope.onUpload = function(e) {
      var saveUrl = e.sender.options.async.saveUrl;
      e.sender.options.async.saveUrl = saveUrl.replace("{board}", $scope.modelObj.board)
    }
  });
})();
```